# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property, if property is not present as a column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Getting following exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: primaryAddress of: com.hcentive.user.ContactInfo
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1805) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1780) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumnsUsingProjection(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.criterion.Order.toSqlString(Order.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getOrderBy(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:414) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.(CriteriaLoader.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1773) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)

while sorting address column in datatable which is defined as:

```
{
                            "mData": function (customer) {
                                var address = customer.userProfile.contactInfo.primaryAddress;
                                return address ? address.displayString : "";

                            },
                            "aTargets": [4],
                            "sName": "userProfile.contactInfo.primaryAddress",
                            "sClass": "wrapWord100"
                         },
```

primaryAddress is present as a getter in ContactInfo.java entity

```
public Address getPrimaryAddress() {
    for (Address add : addresses) {
        if (null != add && AddressTypeEnum.Primary.toString().equals(add.getType())) {
            return add;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
```

The error may be because 'primaryAddress' is not present as a column in 'ContactInfo'.
How to resolve this.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "CONTACT_INFO")
    public class ContactInfo extends Persistent {

    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();

    @Valid
        public Address getPrimaryAddress() {
            for (Address add : addresses) {
                if (null != add && AddressTypeEnum.Primary.toString().equals(add.getType())) {
                    return add;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: primaryAddress is not a member of your ContactInfo, right? If yes, It's normal that Hibernate threw that exception.

Comment: getter and setter are present for primaryAddress in ContactInfo and it is showing in the datatable on UI as well : userProfile.contactInfo.primaryAddress. How can I fix the exception without much code change?

Comment: Could you provide the code of ContactInfo?

Comment: Attached a snippet.

Comment: OK, your ContactInfo has only one member: addresses. This one will be considered as a column in your table contactInfo. Otherwise, primaryAddress is not a member although you named setter and getter for it.

Comment: I'm sorry for not well understanding you see the problem. Why don't you add a member primaryAddess to your contactInfo class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query to this. Also this will return a list of address and not single address.

```
"mData": function (customer) {
                                var address = customer.userProfile.contactInfo.addresses;
                                return address ? address.displayString : "";

                            },
                            "aTargets": [4],
                            "sName": "userProfile.contactInfo.addresses",
                            "sClass": "wrapWord100"
                         },
```

Comment: I need only the primary address. How will sorting work if multiple address are there?

Comment: You need to have left join and then check for primary condition in where clause.